# Textblock with link to text file inside

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, hyperlink, textblock

I am setting  different text to a textblock depending on what control has been selected as a way of providing help for the user.

What I would like to do is in the code behind file, when one control is selected, provide a brief explanation in text, then provide a link to a text file within that textblock.

It might look like, for example "Your choice should be a car manufacturer. Click **here** to see a list"

I was trying to do it with a hyperlink but i'm not having much luck.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the TextBlock.Inlines collection and add a Hyperlink:

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Name="hintInfo" />
```

Code:

```
Hyperlink hlink = new Hyperlink(new Run("here"));
hlink.Click += SomeEventHandler;  // event handler to open text file

hintInfo.Inlines.Clear();
hintInfo.Inlines.Add("Click ");
hintInfo.Inlines.Add(hlink);
hintInfo.Inlines.Add(" to see more info.");
```

To display the text file, you could use Process.Start to launch an external viewer (e.g. Notepad), or you could use File.ReadAllText to read it in, and then display it in a TextBlock or whatever within your app.

Comment: Thank you, just what I was after